# beginner swift sprite kit - arc4random and getting screen size

Tags: xcode, swift, margin, arc4random

I want to get a random number to be in between my background width and to be 37 pixels away from the margins but it doesn't work

```
var width = UInt32(self.frame.width - 74)
var newX = Int(arc4random)%width)
var newY = Int(self.frame.height+10)
var pos = CGPoint(x: newX + 37, y: newY)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arc4random` is a function, you need to call it. And you should be using `arc4random_uniform` anyway.

```
var newX = Int(arc4random_uniform(width))
```

Also, because Swift is still terrible about implicit conversions, you need to convert the arguments to the `CGPoint`:

```
var pos = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(newX + 37), y: CGFloat(newY))
```

And if you don't intend to change these later in the method, you should use `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: It still spawns Nodes on the border .. I don't think var width is correct.